# Método em Loop Infinito

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss-weld

Possuo uma chamada de método que é efetuada com `<p:remoteCommand />` do Primefaces na Página Principal do meu sistema. E funciona perfeitamente com alguns usuários, mas com outros ele passa pelo método no Bean completo, mas nunca finaliza. O loop acontece dentro da implementação do próprio JSF, mas não consigo acompanhar com o Debug porque não possuo os fontes, então não sei ao certo onde ocorre.

Faço o bloqueio da tela para o usuário com o `<p:blockUI />`. E por esse motivo, o usuário nunca passa dessa parte. A única diferença entre os usuários é que a lista para popular o gráfico vem vazia, mas sem o uso do `<p:remoteCommand />` nunca tive problemas com isso.

Remote Command:

```html
<h:form id="remoteCommandForm">
<p:remoteCommand 
 action="#{paginaInicialBean.inicializar()}" 
 autoRun="true"
 update="formIndex"
 onstart="PF('blockUIWidget').show();"
 oncomplete="PF('blockUIWidget').hide();" />
</h:form>
```

BlockUI:

```html
<p:blockUI
    widgetVar="blockUIWidget"
    block=":body"
    styleClass="blockui-background">

    <h:outputText 
      value="Por favor, aguarde.."
      escape="false" />

    <br />
    <br />

    <p:graphicImage 
      library="imagens" 
      name="loading_ring_1.gif"
      width="70px"
      height="70px" />
  </p:blockUI>
```

Método Bean:

```
public void inicializar() throws SistemaException {

    inicializaConfiguracaoGrafico();

    Cliente clienteLogado = seguranca.getClienteAutenticado();
    carregar(clienteLogado);
    idFilialSelecionado = clienteLogado.getCodAtual();

    criarGraficoQuantidadeUnidadeBarChartModelo();
    criarGraficoQuantidadePorcentagemBarChartModelo();
    criarGraficoValorPorcentagemBarChartModelo();
    criarGraficoValorUnidadeBarChartModelo();

    trataMudancaGrafico();

    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.update("controleGrafico");

}
```

Comment: Para ter um *loop*  infinito precisaria ter um *loop*, não?

Comment: Ou uma chamada recursiva. Isso acontece depois que ele finaliza meu método, quando o JSF atualiza as EL, e isso acontece nas classes da biblioteca do Mojarra.

Comment: Se é um chamada recursiva seria uma recursão infinita, o que não ocorre também em nenhum trecho demonstrado.